# Angular 4 spinner

Tags: angular

if someone can help me solve this, I want the spinner to appear while charging, currently it does not work, does anyone know what I can improve to start? Angular 4

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationCancel, NavigationError, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.css']
})
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoading: Boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent));
  }

  public checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event) {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      console.log('true');
    } else if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd || routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel || routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log('false');
    }
  }

}

<div *ngIf="isLoading" id="preloader">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: It does not show any error, but this function is not performed because it does not show the log, I do not know why. The compiler only highlights this line
 ` ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent));
  }`

Comment: @Wojtar please have a look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512285/angular-httpclient-show-spinner-progress-indicator-while-waiting-for-service-t/45512504#45512504)

Comment: These are quite different solutions, can not mine be improved to start working?

Comment: Comment out this.isLoading = false; to see if it shows up in the first place. Then you know where to look. Also a simple navigation goes by really quickly, so personally I would skip the loader for router events and have it for Http events, which can then be controlled via an interceptor.

Comment: I commented and the spinner showed up

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the spinner on loading then you should change the condition in html / component

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoading" id="preloader">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

**or**

```
isLoading: Boolean = true;

public checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event) {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log('true');
    } else if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd || routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel || routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log('false');
    }
  }
```

so that the spinner will be shown in the begining and on response it will vanish.